# Convert single column of table into rows

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I'm still pretty new to programming so I appreciate all the help I get. I want to produce a report that looks like this, in order to create a table that shows me, whether we already have a description to an activity in every language.

```
Activity  | Texttype      | ENG  | GER |  ESP ...
Bustour     Description     X      X
            Title                  X      X
            Slogan          X      X      X
Dinner      Description     X      X      X
...
```

The problem is, that I can't limit the languages or the Texttypes, because there are new ones everyday.

My output looks like this right now:

```
Activity  | Texttype      | Language
Bustour     Description     English
                            German
            Title           German
                            Spanish
            Slogan          English
                            German
                            Spanish
Dinner      Description     English
                            German
                            Spanish
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this table?
I really appreciate every help, I've been stuck on this problem for days..

Thank you in advance and greetings,

Vivess

Comment: You should use [crosstab](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/crosstabs/index.html#crosstabs)

Answer (score 0):

could be using case when

```
select Activity, Texttype, case when ENG = 'x' then 'English'
                                when GER = 'x' then 'German'
                                when ESP = 'x' then 'Spanish'
                                .....
                            end as Language

from my_table 
order by Activity, Texttype, Language
```

Comment: How it can help to build report with floating number of columns?

Comment: That would only work if I would already have the columns and if I could limit the languages..

Comment: excalty .. is just a suggestion .. if you need some more dinamic could be you need somethings server side  .. not only sql based